# Is there a conventional symbol for the set of real algebraic numbers?

Tags: notation, terminology, real-numbers, number-systems, algebraic-numbers

The real numbers are denoted $\mathbb R$, and the algebraic numbers are conventionally denoted $\mathbb A$. Is there such convention for the real algebraic numbers $\mathbb R \cap \mathbb A$?

Comment: $\mathbb A$ is used often, but not by everybody.

Comment: You could just define the set in a preamble if you can't find suitable notation. If the notation's too obscure, you may need to do that anyway.

Comment: Thanks. @YiorgosS.Smyrlis: So  is sometimes used for the real, and sometimes the complex case? I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Thanks. @EulCan: As suggested, I would define my notation, but I'd prefer to follow an existing convention if one exists.

Comment: Following the comment from YiorgosS.Smyrlis, I suppose I could use  for the reals and (i) for the complex case.

Comment: I use $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ to denote the algebraic numbers. $\mathbb{A}$ is confusing because it clashes with notation for the adeles (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adele_ring).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned there isn't a "global" convention on such such a notation. So I would suggest simply defining your notation.